# Let $M\subset l^{\infty}$ be the subspace of $\; l^{\infty}$ consisting of all sequences $(x_{i})$ with at

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Please let me know if the solution to the following problem is true. Just a **hint** can be enough.
**Problem**:

> Let $M\subset l^{\infty}$ be the subspace of  $\; l^{\infty}$ consisting of all sequences $(x_{i})$ with at most finitely many nonzero terms. Find a Cauchy sequence in $M$ which does not converge in $M$, so that $M$ is not complete.

**What I have done**:

> Define 
>   $x_{n}=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\cdots , \frac{1}{n},0,0,\cdots\}$
>   So we have for any m\leq n,
>   $$ d(x_{n},x_{m})=\vert x_{n}-x_{m}\vert= \{ 0,\cdots,0,\frac{1}{m+1},\dots, \frac{1}{n},0,\cdots\}, $$
>   so we see that $d(x_{n},x_{m})\to 0\; $ as $\;m,n\to\infty.$
>   Therefore, ${x_{n}}$ is a Cauchy sequence. On the contrary, $x_{n}\to x$ as $n\to \infty,$ where $x=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\cdots , \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},\cdots\}$ which does not belong to $M.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is just fine. You proved that $M$ is not complete by providing an example of a Cauchy sequence of elements of $M$ which does not converge in $M$.

Comment: I'm in doubt ın my sentence to say $d(x_{n}, x_{m})\to 0$ because if $m$ and $n$ tends to infinity so $x_{m}$ and $x_{n}$ cant be belong to $M$ because $m$ and $n$ must be finite.

Comment: Note that, if $m\neq n$, $d_\infty(x_m,x_n)=\max\{\frac1m,\frac1n\}$. It should be clear that this quantity goes to $0$ when $m$ and $n$ are large enough.

Comment: But I read 
$ d(x_{n},x_{m})=\vert x_{n}-x_{m}\vert= \{ 0,\cdots,0,\frac{1}{m+1},\dots, \frac{1}{n},0,\cdots\}, $
you says that $d(x_{m},x_{n})=\max \{1/m,1/n\}$. Which one is true? It seems that I should change the metric.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari Actually, I failed to notice that there's a problem with your metric. Please note that $d\infty(x_m,x_n)$ must be a non-negative real number. It cannot possibly be a set.

Answer (score 2):

Your metric outputs a set and not a non-negative real number.  The metric I suspect you are using is $d(\{y_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N},\{\tilde y_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}):=\sup_j |y_j-\tilde y_j|$.  Now to prove your statement you should show that your sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy for the metric $d$. Then take any element $m\in M$ and show that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that  $d(x_n,m)\ge\varepsilon$ for all $n$ large.

Do you see the difference from your approach?

Comment: No, I could not see it.  Would you mind explaining more?

Comment: If you show (1) $\{x_n\}_n\subset (M,d)$ is Cauchy, and (2) $x_n\to x $ in $(l^\infty,d)$ with $x\in l^\infty\backslash M$, you have not shown that $\{x_n\}_n$ does not converge in $(M,d)$. You need a (little) extra step.